# mysql : select where with group by with GROUP_CONCAT(col_name SEPARATOR ', ')

Tags: mysql, sql

Table content :

```
number  value
   1     123
   1     345
```

I have above table content , I want below output when I do a select:

```
number   value
   1     123,345
```

But i get

```
number   value
   1      345
```

sql am using  :

```
SELECT  number, GROUP_CONCAT(value SEPARATOR ', ') as val,
from table_name 
where value="345"
group by number
```

The reason for using value where clause is

- The output should have 123,345 (because `number` 1 is associated with both `value`) . So i want both value seperated with comma.
- I dont want to remove the where clause for `value` because I wanted to query by that as well
- In simple words its just like 123 in (grouped `value` value)

Can any one tell me where am I going wrong ?

Comment: Please don't post images of sample data or results.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the query you mentioned in your question is what you actually ran, or what generated the output your showed us.  Rather, I think you ran this query:

```
SELECT
    number,
    GROUP_CONCAT(value SEPARATOR ', ') AS val
FROM table_name
WHERE value = '345'
GROUP BY number
```

The problem is your `WHERE` clause, which is retricting the aggregation to just one record.  Remove it and you should get the result you expect:

```
SELECT
    number,
    GROUP_CONCAT(value) AS val
FROM table_name
GROUP BY number
```

Comment: Updated my Question !!

Comment: @dishanm My query is valid and is reasonable given the sample data you gave in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
SELECT number, GROUP_CONCAT(value SEPARATOR ', ') as val 
FROM table_name
GROUP BY number
HAVING MAX(value = '345') > 0;
```

This will return all values for any number that has `'345'` as at least one value.

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/89983/1) is a SQL Fiddle showing that it works.

Comment: Nope !! It still returns me single record. Tried your suggestion in sql fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/829df/2/0

Comment: @dishanm . . . Your SQL Fiddle was broken.

Comment: @dishanm . . . Your sample data is broken.  You have two different values for `number`.  They will not be combined.

Comment: @dishanm Ranting won't get you an answer any faster.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff : Pasting the sql fiddle i used Sql schema: CREATE TABLE tab ( ID int, col varchar(1000) ); INSERT INTO tab VALUES (1, '999'); INSERT INTO tab VALUES (2, '12345'); SELECT query : SELECT id, GROUP_CONCAT(col SEPARATOR ', ') as val FROM tab GROUP BY id HAVING MAX(col = '999') > 0;